# Multer array returns only one file

Tags: node.js, gridfs, multer

I'm using multer to store multiple files in the database.

The files are stored properly in my DB, however, if I print `req.files` I only get just one file.

This is my code:

```
var storage = GridfsStorage({
  url: config.mongo.uri,
  filename(req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.originalname);
  },
  metadata(req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, {owner: req.params.driver})
  }
});

var upload = multer({ storage: storage }).array('files[]');

return upload(req, res, function (err) {
    if(err) {
      handleError(err);
    }
    console.log(req.files); // --> Getting only one file, even thought it stores all of them
    respondWithResult(req.files, 201);
})
```

Thanks for helping!

Comment: The `[]` in the fieldname part looks suspect to me, try `array('documents')` just to rule any foul play out there.

Comment: Yes, I thought that as well, but I am using UIkit frameworks and it's the default name of the fieldname... I did try what you say, but is still the same, I just get the first uploaded file in array format...